# Does \w match all alphanumeric characters defined in the Unicode standard?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, internationalization, character-properties

**Does Perl's `\w` match all alphanumeric characters defined in the Unicode standard?**

For example, will `\w` match all (say) Chinese and Russian alphanumeric characters?

I wrote a simple test script (see below) which suggests that `\w` does indeed match "as expected" for the non-ASCII alphanumeric characters I tested. But the testing is obviously far from exhaustive.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                                                                                                  

use utf8;

binmode(STDOUT, ':utf8');

my @ok;
$ok[0] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$ok[1] = "éèëáàåäöčśžłíżńęøáýąóæšćôı";
$ok[2] = "şźüęłâi̇ółńśłŕíáυσνχατςęςη";
$ok[3] = "τσιαιγολοχβςανنيرحبالтераб";
$ok[4] = "иневоаслкłјиневоцедањеволс";
$ok[5] = "рглсывызтоμςόκιναςόγο";

foreach my $ok (@ok) {
    die unless ($ok =~ /^\w+$/);
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[perldoc perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html) says

> Character classes in regular expressions match characters instead of bytes and match against the character properties specified in the Unicode properties database. `\w` can be used to match a Japanese ideograph, for instance.

So it looks like the answer to your question is "yes".

However, you might want to use the `\p{}` construct to directly access specific [Unicode character properties](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Unicode-Character-Properties). You can probably use `\p{L}` (or, shorter, `\pL`) for letters and `\pN` for numbers and feel a little more confident that you'll get exactly what you want.

Comment: Note that that depends on character semantics; if your string came from a source using byte semantics, `\w` will only match ASCII word characters.

Comment: For more details on Unicode character semantics, see [The Unicode Bug in perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#The-%22Unicode-Bug%22).  The safe equivalent to `\w` is to use `\p{Alnum}`.

Comment: @cjm, `\w` is actually `\p{Word}`. `\p{Alnum}` lacks the underscore.

Comment: @Anomie: There’s also the locale issue.

Comment: @CanSpice: "Letter" != "Alphabetic".  You must never use `\pL` to mean `\p{Alphabetic}`.  They’re really quite different. As of Unicode 6, there are 1006 code points that have the Alphabetic property but which lack the GC=Letter property.

Answer (score 12):

Yes and no.

If you want all alphanumerics, you want `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{GC=Number}]`.  The `\w` contains both more and less than that.  It specifically excludes any `\pN` which is not `\p{Nd}` nor `\p{Nl}`, like the superscripts, subscripts, and fractions.  Those are `\p{GC=Other_Number}`, and are not included in `\w`.

Because unlike most regex systems, Perl complies with [Requirement 1.2a, “Compatibility Properties”](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties) from [UTS #18 on Unicode Regular Expressions](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/), then **assuming you have Unicode strings,** a `\w` in a regex matches any single code point that has any of the following four properties:

1. `\p{GC=Alphabetic}`
2. `\p{GC=Mark}`
3. `\p{GC=Connector_Punctuation}`
4. `\p{GC=Decimal_Number}`

Number 4 above can be expressed in any of these ways, which are all considered equivalent:

- `\p{Digit}`
- `\p{General_Category=Decimal_Number}`
- `\p{GC=Decimal_Number}`
- `\p{Decimal_Number}`
- `\p{Nd}`
- `\p{Numeric_Type=Decimal}`
- `\p{Nt=De}`

Note that `\p{Digit}` is not the same as `\p{Numeric_Type=Digit}`. For example, code point B2, SUPERSCRIPT TWO, has only the `\p{Numeric_Type=Digit}` property and not plain `\p{Digit}`. That is because it is considered a `\p{Other_Number}` or `\p{No}`.  It does, however, have the `\p{Numeric_Value=2}` property as you would imagine.

It’s really point number 1 above, `\p{Alphabetic}` ,that gives people the most trouble. That’s  because they too often mistakenly think it is somehow the same as `\p{Letter}` (`\pL`), but it is not.

Alphabetics include much more than that, all because of the `\p{Other_Alphabetic}` property, as this in turn 
includes **some but not** all `\p{GC=Mark}`, all of `\p{Lowercase}` (which is not the same as `\p{GC=Ll}` because it adds `\p{Other_Lowercase}`) and  all of `\p{Uppercase}` (which is not the same as `\p{GC=Lu}` because it adds `\p{Other_Uppercase}`).

That’s how it pulls in `\p{GC=Letter_Number}` like Roman numerals and also 
all the circled letters, which are of type `\p{Other_Symbol}` and `\p{Block=Enclosed_Alphanumerics}`.

Aren’t you glad we get to use `\w`? :)

Comment: How is it sensible that "other alphabetic" includes GC=Mark ?  How is it sensible that "Lowercase" not the same as GC=Ll ?  baffling.

Answer (score 2):

In particular `\w` also matches the underscore character.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$name = 'Arun_Kumar';
($name =~ /\w+/)? print "Underscore is a word character\n": print "No underscores\n";
$ underscore.pl
```

Underscore is a word character.