# How to improve this code? Extract info using Regex

Tags: r, regex

I have this dataframe with some data that I'm triying to extract, I don't actually have a problem but I feel like there should be a better / more elegant way to do it.

So, I have this string

```
CVEGEO=0901500011337<BR>CVE_ENT=09<BR>CVE_MUN=015<BR>CVE_LOC=0001<BR>CVE_AGEB=1337<BR>
```

136 times and I'm interested on `MUN=(.*) and AGEB=(.*)`

To obtain the info I use:

```
test1 <- sub(".*_MUN=(.*)<BR>CVE_LOC=0001<BR>CVE_AGEB=(.*)<.*", "\\1_\\2", L1_AGEB$description)
str_split_fixed(test1, "_", 2)
```

And it works just fine, but, like I said, and this is just for academic/improvement purposes Is there an easier/elegant way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56676375/6553328) is inefficient. Here, maybe, we'd just use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` which might insignificantly perform  better with regards to time and space complexities, that I'm just guessing,  and just like you've mentioned, your original expression is just fine, lookaround is usually not recommended, nor any other fancy methods, when we'd work with regular expressions.

```
MUN=([0-9]+).+AGEB=([0-9]+)
```

#### [Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56676375/6553328)

I'm pretty sure there should be other ways to improve upon what we wish to accomplish here, yet the key point is that, your original expression is already following a right path, but maybe not the right one, which for this reason we'd have likely traded off the desired elegancy.

Please see other views in the comments, and I'm only referencing, don't really have an opinion/recommendation here, even though it might sound otherwise.

#### References

- [2013: \d is less efficient than [0-9]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9)
- [2019: RegEx word performance: \w vs [a-zA-Z0-9_]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699393/regex-word-performance-w-vs-a-za-z0-9)
- [2018: Difference between [0-9], [[:digit:]] and \d](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414226/difference-between-0-9-digit-and-d)
- [2010: What's the Time Complexity of Average Regex algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892115/whats-the-time-complexity-of-average-regex-algorithms)

Comment: I would be careful with a 2013 link post. Today, `\d` matches these Unicode ranges in UTF-8/32 regex:  `[0-9٠-٩۰-۹߀-߉०-९০-৯੦-੯૦-૯୦-୯௦-௯౦-౯೦-೯൦-൯෦-෯๐-๙໐-໙༠-༩၀-၉႐-႙០-៩᠐-᠙᥆-᥏᧐-᧙᪀-᪉᪐-᪙᭐-᭙᮰-᮹᱀-᱉᱐-᱙꘠-꘩꣐-꣙꤀-꤉꧐-꧙꧰-꧹꩐-꩙꯰-꯹０-９----------------------]`

Comment: As performance goes, ranges in classes is the slowest, followed by sequences. Speedwise, `\d` is an intrinsic api function `isdigit()` which takes a shorter time than the others.  `Regex1:   [0123456789]
Matches found per iteration:   62
Elapsed Time: 2.36 s,   2363.61 ms,   2363615 µs
Matches per sec:  1,311,550
Regex2:   [0-9]
Matches found per iteration:   62
Elapsed Time:  2.62 s,   2620.44 ms,   2620444 µs
Matches per sec:  1,183,005
Regex3:   \d Matches found per iteration:   62
Elapsed Time:  2.20 s,   2196.97 ms,   2196974 µs
Matches per sec:   1,411,031`

Answer (score 1):

Definitely take a look at the `rex` package,
it has a learning curve,
but it can be pretty nifty:

```
library(rex)

rex::re_matches("CVEGEO=0901500011337<BR>CVE_ENT=09<BR>CVE_MUN=015<BR>CVE_LOC=0001<BR>CVE_AGEB=1337<BR>",
                pattern = rex::rex(
                  "MUN=",
                  capture(any_numbers, name = "MUN"),
                  anything,
                  "AGEB=",
                  capture(any_numbers, name = "AGEB")
                ))
  MUN AGEB
1 015 1337
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `regmatches` / `regexpr` approach with a PCRE regex that will extract 1+ digits after the known "prefixes":

```
x <- "CVEGEO=0901500011337<BR>CVE_ENT=09<BR>CVE_MUN=015<BR>CVE_LOC=0001<BR>CVE_AGEB=1337<BR>"
regmatches(x, regexpr("_MUN=\\K\\d+", x, perl=TRUE))
## => [1] "015"
regmatches(x, regexpr("_AGEB=\\K\\d+", x, perl=TRUE))
## => [1] "1337"
```

See  the [R demo](https://ideone.com/Tcax4Y) online.

**Regex details**

- `_MUN=` - a `_MUN` text
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.

The use of `perl=TRUE` is crucial for the regex to work.

Equivalent using `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "(?<=_MUN=)\\d+")
str_extract(x, "(?<=_AGEB=)\\d+")
```

The `(?<=...)` positive lookbehind only checks for the pattern match immediately to the left of the current location, but does not consume the text, i.e. does not put it into the match value.

And a fancy solution with `stringr::str_match` capturing the results in one go into Columns 2 and 3:

```
library(stringr)
str_match(x, "_MUN=(\\d+).*_AGEB=(\\d+)")
#      [,1]                                        [,2]  [,3]  
# [1,] "_MUN=015<BR>CVE_LOC=0001<BR>CVE_AGEB=1337" "015" "1337"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can completely parse the entire input by converting the input to DCF format.  This has the advantage that any of the fields can easily be subsequently extracted.

Assuming the input `x` shown in the Note at the end, we can replace `<BR>` with newline and replace `=` with colon and then read what is left using `read.dcf`. No packages are used.

```
x2 <- gsub("=", ":", gsub("<BR>", "\n", x))
read.dcf(textConnection(x2))
```

giving this character matrix:

```
     CVEGEO          CVE_ENT CVE_MUN CVE_LOC CVE_AGEB
[1,] "0901500011337" "09"    "015"   "0001"  "1337"  
[2,] "0901500011337" "09"    "015"   "0001"  "1337"  
[3,] "0901500011337" "09"    "015"   "0001"  "1337"
```

A variation of this using the magrittr package would be:

```
library(magrittr)
x %>%
  gsub("<BR>", "\n", .) %>%
  gsub("=", ":", .) %>%
  textConnection %>%
  read.dcf
```

### Note

```
x <- "CVEGEO=0901500011337<BR>CVE_ENT=09<BR>CVE_MUN=015<BR>CVE_LOC=0001<BR>CVE_AGEB=1337<BR>"
x <- rep(x, 3)
```