# Subtract from a character class

Tags: python, regex

Is there any way to subtract from an existing character class code? For example, let's say I want to get `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, and the closest is `\w`, which expands to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Is there a way to do something like:

- `[\w-_]`

Or do we just have to re-write the class, i.e., `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: `[^\W_]`. Or `(?!_)\w`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. When writing a regex, do you prefer using `[a-zA-Z0-9]` or one of your suggestions? Or it doesn't matter for you

Comment: In Python, it matters a lot. If I need my regex to match Unicode letters or digits, I'd use `[^\W_]`. If I have to only match ASCII letters and digits, I'd use `[A-Za-z0-9]`. Actually, you are wrong saying "*`\w`... expands to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`*". It expands to much more chars by default (if you do not use `(?a)` inline modifier or the `re.ASCII` flag). See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64794482/3832970) for more details.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's great, thank you very much, especially for the `\w` comment.